# MVC .NET How to add unit test project in for existing source code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

I've already created MVC project (VS2008 .NET 3.5) 
at first time VS2008 ask me 
"Would you like to create Unit test project for this application ?" 
I choose No..

Now I realize that it's growing more complex and TDD (test driven development) approach would have been better.

but can't find out how to add a unit test project in my solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

[How to: Create a Test Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182413.aspx)

As described in the following procedures, you can create test projects in several ways:

- [Create a test project when you add a
  test.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182413.aspx#CreateTPWhenAddTest) When you create a new test, you
  can create new a test project into
  which the test will be added, or add
  the test to an existing test project
  that is already loaded.
- [Create a test project when you
  generate a unit test.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182413.aspx#CreateTPWhenGenerate) When you
  generate unit tests, you can create a
  new test project into which the tests
  will be added, or add them to an
  existing test project.
- [Using the Add New Project dialog box.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182413.aspx#CreateTPAddNewProjectDB)
  With this method, you use a dialog
  box to choose the programming
  language of your test project.

Comment: How do I add individual test methods to actions? There is no "Add test method" in the context menu like I'm used to in Windows app development.

Comment: @Shimmy you can add a unit test for a given controller action in VS 2015 by right-clicking on the action name and selecting Create Unit Tests from the context menu. The question does mention VS 2008, but I'm not sure if that feature was available at that time.

Answer (score 6):

Just use Add -> New Project

Either add a simple Class Library, and manually add a reference to the unit test framework of your choice, or use the "Unit test project" template that comes with visual studio (for use with MSTest)

Comment: I am beginner and I already have a complex web site built. And I need to unit test it. Can you kindly tell me the steps. Or pass on any link which I can follow along. I don't know about class libraries or "test framework of your choice". Is there any material for beginner which I can follow along. Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the generated unit test project has some example tests for the default project controllers, etc..

If you want to use the generated unit test project as a starting point, you could always create a new ASP.NET MVC solution, select 'Yes' this time, and then copy that into your project.  You'll have to update the references to correctly point to your project of course..

Comment: That is an idea I have come up with too.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the "Add -> New Project" method:

1. Right click on your solution in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Add" -> "New Project".
3. Select "Test" from the template list, and then select "Unit Test Project". Name your Project (I have heard that scaffolding will only work if you name your test project: "{YourProjectName}.Tests"), and click "OK".
4. Your project will be created with a default unit test class file, where you can put your tests, OR:
5. You can right click any of the methods in your main project and select "Create Unit Tests" and select your newly created "Unit Test Project" as the place where your unit tests will live.
6. Depending on your project type, you may also need to add references to the various assemblies, I found this answer to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130164/6762843
7. And, if you get an error saying "instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" that means that you need to add an App.config file to your test project and copy the connection string from your main project.

Comment: Thank you. It never worked for me (or allowed me to create a reference) if I didn't name it that way.