# How Can I Add a Unit Test Project to an Existing MVC3 Application (from empty template)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd

I created an MVC3 application from the Empty template so I couldn´t add a Visual Studio Unit test project to the solution.

I made some changes, added some controllers and now I want to try TDD so I need to add a framework for testing.

But I can´t see how I can do that.

I want some way where I can create my test project right in the Solution Explorer, for example  "website.Test" with some basic folders and files.

I saw here some questions about how to add Unit tests, but those were with xUnit.net or NUnit and I want the original VS test framework.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I am also interested to know what others think about the 3rd-party unit test frameworks, are they better?

What about for beginners?

Comment: Do you just want to create an empty test project insade your mvc app solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add an empty Test project just go to File>Add>New Project choose Test subcategory > Test Project.

Comment: I found this, but is it for website?

Comment: This type of project is for any type of application. Test project template is actually just a specialized Library project.

Answer (score 17):

The naming of the test-project is significant! If your MVC-project is named "MyProject" your test-project has to be named "MyProject.Tests" in order to connect both of them. Tools like MvcScaffolding will not work otherwise!

Answer (score 12):

`File > Add > New Project > Test > Unit Test Project`, which has name: "{ProjectName}.**Tests**". Next step's to add References, best way's to open your {ProjectName} -> References and r-click on System.Web. Mvc, look:

[image]

Then will open a new window, copy path to file:

[image]

And add your reference :-) to **unit test project**:

[image]

Then select `Browse` and go to **Dictionary** (remember to delete filename, f.e: `g:\disk\yourdll.dll` = `g:\disk\`):

[image]

Next step's similar but add your {ProjectName}.dll by this way:

`{ProjectName}.Tests -> References -> Add` and Add {ProjectName}.dll:

[image]

Follow with presented steps and add references from your {ProjectName} to {ProjectName}.Tests.

**Important dll:**

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor
- System.Web.Razor

Comment: What do you mean by this `Then select Browse and go to Dictionary (remember to delete filename):` and the image below it? I don't understand.

Comment: remember to delete filename - because you want to open file from directory...you can immediately add file by full path, or manual -> go to directory (by path with removed filaname+extension) and find file + add it.

Answer (score 1):

For your Solution do "File->New->Project". Select "Test->Unit Test Project". Then for a name enter "YourSolution.Tests" and press OK. Next add a reference to YourSolution: on "YourSolution.Tests->References" right click and browse to Solutions, make sure that there is a check box selected for YourSolution and press Ok.