# Adding Unit Test Project to ASP.Net MVC 4 Project

Tags: mstest, asp.net-mvc-4

Just like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256932/mvc-net-how-to-add-unit-test-project-in-for-existing-source-code), I didn't create a unit test project for my MVC 4 project when it was first created.  Now I want to go back and add one.

To that end, I created a new Unit Test Project.

Now, I right-click on a private method in one of my controllers, select Create Unit Tests, and get a popup dialog asserting:

> Unit Test Generation Error: The following error was encountered while reading module 
>   'My.Project': Could not resolve the type reference: [System.Web.Mvc, Version 3.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={why doesn't MS support cut and 
>   paste??}]System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute.

AllowAnonymousAttribute is new to MVC 4.  Why is the Unit Test Generator trying to resolve against the MVC 3 assembly though?

My.Project compiles and runs just fine, AllowAnonymousAttribute and all, and clearly is reverencing System.Web.Mvc, Version 4.0.0.0.

**UPDATE**

*MyMvc.csproj contains*

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetMvc.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The DLL at HintPath is confirmed to be version 4.0.0.0

*MyMvc.Test.csproj contains*

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in VS2012.

VS2012 no longer supports the add unit test wizard.  Manually added unit tests work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Download Resharper (there's a free 30 day trail) and press alt+enter. It will automatically add what is needed.

Comment: That did not fix the problem.